# Working alongside a partner who makes noises with their mouth

Tags: communication, work-environment, offices, noise

Due to an accident that I suffered recently, I have problems in my jaw, I am generating much more saliva than usual, and therefore I cannot help making some constant minor noises and swallowing saliva.

Only my boss and the occupational doctors know about my accident. And I'm sure it doesn't show on my face that I had this accident.

Luckily it will be solved in 8 days when I have surgery. A complicated operation, in which they will drill me from the outside, general anesthesia, etc ... But fortunately with a 100% recovery. But in the meantime, in these 8 long days, I am trying my best to fulfill my obligations despite my discomfort. I share an office with people from other areas that I don't know. It may be my imagination, but sometimes I feel like when I make a noise they stop writing or take a deep breath. Simply, I just feel, or intuit, a certain general malaise.

I don't think the noise is more detrimental than a distraction, as it is only a minor sound, much less than a snoring.

It would be ethical to tell them about my situation, the ethical thing is to wait for someone to express their discomfort to me about the noise to give them the corresponding explanation?

Comment: “Ethics” have nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: @mxyzplk They might if they have reason to suspect that one of their coworkers suffers from misophonia, for instance (in which case the correct action would be for the boss to come up with reasonable accommodations for both workers, in accordance with any disability laws applicable in their area).

Answer (score 8):

I think it's probably mostly in your head, but if you really think it's bothering people, I don't think there's anything wrong with an email to the people that you think are being bothered saying something like "Sorry about the noise.  It's the result of a medical condition due to an accident.  Luckily, I'll be having surgery to fix it in a week.  Hope I don't bother everyone too much until then"

Comment: @StephanBranczyk One email, which can be well thought out and requires no response, vs multiple conversations where people my feel the need to respond

Answer (score 3):

> It would be ethical to tell them about my situation, the ethical thing is to wait for someone to express their discomfort to me about the noise to give them the corresponding explanation?

I wouldn't frame this as ethical or not. But yes you are free to tell anyone about your situation, if you are ok with that.

However, if this will be through in 8 days (after surgery) I don't see why bother doing so, but again, you are free to chose.

It would be unreasonable for someone to complain if the noises are minor or comparable to regular background noise in an office. Perhaps you are worrying without need to...

Hope you recover swiftly from the surgery.

Comment: I forgot to clarify that in that place where I am, there is generally a deathly silence. So the background noise from the office does not exist.

Comment: Yet, you say that the noises are minor, so they still shouldn't cause discomfort to anybody... if you are really worried about the chance that anybody could complain, then perhaps you want to consider disclosing this to your coworkers... this could bring you peace of mind... for 8 days then problem gone so, if it where me I wouldn't bother...

Comment: Minor is in the ear of the beholder and frequency of the noise also matters.  This has the potential to be very annoying to those around OP, even though no fault of their own.  It isn't up to OP to decide whether someone should be bothered by this level of noise.  There is nothing wrong with a co-worker being bothered by this when they have no other information.